# iOS Location Updates not trigerred consistently in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

Requirement:
To Trigger Location update Callback after every second when the app is in background.

Problem:
Location Callbacks are not triggered after every second. Instead we get them inconsistently sometimes after 1 second, sometimes after 4 second and even with gap of 40-50 seconds.

Current Implementation:

```
setActivityType = CLActivityTypeOther
setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES
setDesiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
setDistanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

plist configuration also done for background location updates.

Please suggest what more can be done to achieve solution for this problem?

Comment: Which option are you using to update location. Is it `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` or `startUpdatingLocation`?

Comment: By the way have you turned on `Location updates` in  `Background Modes` section under `Capabilites`?

Comment: @Poles: I am using startUpdatingLocation Methods and Yes I have turned on the Location flag in Capabilities section.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code for background location updation when a significant location change is occured:

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManager

- (void)startContinuosLocationUpdate
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        NSLog(@"Location services are disabled in settings.");
    }
    else
    {
        // for iOS 8
        if ([self.anotherLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
        {
            [self.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        // for iOS 9
        if ([self.anotherLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)])
        {
            [self.anotherLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
        }

        [self.anotherLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)stopContinuosLocationUpdate
{
    [self.anotherLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)startMonitoringLocation
{
    if (_anotherLocationManager)
        [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    self.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
    _anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    _anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        [_anotherLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
    }
    else if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)restartMonitoringLocation
{
    [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        [_anotherLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
    }
    else if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```